# Powershell IF ELSE will not run ELSE statement

Tags: powershell

I have the following code that I need to use to switch windows 7 themes between standard and high contrast. The IF runs fine but it will not run the ELSE condition, can someone please point out the error of my ways?

```
IF     ((Get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes").CurrentTheme = "%SystemRoot%\resources\Ease of Access Themes\hcblack.theme") 
       {
       C:\scripts\Themetool.exe changetheme "c:\Windows\resources\Themes\MyTheme.theme"
       } 
ELSE   {
       C:\scripts\Themetool.exe changetheme "C:\Windows\resources\Ease of Access Themes\hcblack.theme"
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning the current theme in the registry.

You need to use `-eq` for equality comparison. `=` is the assign operator in powershell.

[List of powershell operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)

What happens in detail is that your code is first assigning the value `.../hcblack.theme` to `CurrentTheme` and then uses this value for the boolean condition in the if statement. PowerShell treats non empty strings as `$true`. You can try this yourself: `!!"" -eq $false`. That's why the `if` part is matched.

What you are doing could be written as:

```
$prop = Get-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes"
$prop.CurrentTheme = "%SystemRoot%\resources\Ease of Access Themes\hcblack.theme"
if ($prop.CurrentTheme) { ... }
```

What you should do:

```
if ((Get-ItemProperty -path "<path>").CurrentTheme -eq "<value>") { ... }
```